# WPF Layout Control

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am new to WPF. 
I have a wpf window which contains a grid which is dynamic in size along with its columns. This window is supposed to be a small utility type window that is always ontop.

The issue is as the user types into the richtextbox it expands of the bottom of the page, I would like a scroll bar to appear.

I have tried placing it in a  container but this doesnt work.

I want the grid to resize if the user decides to resize the window.

```
<Window 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="202" Width="927" WindowStyle="ToolWindow" ShowInTaskbar="True"   Topmost="True">

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"
                  Grid.Column="1" 
                  Width="1" 
                  ResizeDirection="Columns"/>

    <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                  ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  Grid.Column="3" 
                  Width="1" 
                  ResizeDirection="Columns"/>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Height="Auto">
        <Label Background="SteelBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="white" Height="25">Note</Label>
        <RichTextBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                     ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
        </RichTextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<RichTextBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                 ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                 ***Height="300">***
    </RichTextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

StackPanels do not do vertical layout, you should probably either use a DockPanel or a Grid with two Rows instead, that way the RichTextBox is bounded and knows when to use its scrolling functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Thank H.B replacing StackPanel with grid worked. Alex adding the height didnt work sorry.

So I replace the StackPanel with

```
   <Grid Grid.Column="2">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="25"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Background="SteelBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="white" Height="25">Note</Label>
        <RichTextBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                     ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                     Grid.Row="1">
        </RichTextBox>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Glad that helped. (You could [accept](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+accept+an+answer) my answer by clicking the checkmark outline next to it, you might need to merge accounts first)